# JDBC Error: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oim

I am creating a java scheduled task in OIM. Part of the code is to access OIM database via JDBC. My code below:

```
String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.171.160:1523:IAMDB";
String USER = "username";
String PASS = "password";

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
```

I'm getting error in line 6

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

I tried accessing the database in SQL Developer using the same credentials and it's working

- Hostname: 10.10.171.160
- Port: 1523
- ServiceName: IAMDB

Comment: Must it not be /TAMDB i.o. :TAMDB? The first colons are for protocols and subprotocols, and one colon before the port number, but then slash.

Comment: I tried both and both not working
jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.171.160:1523:IAMDB
jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.171.160:1523/IAMDB

Comment: Do you have connectivity from your app environment? nc -vz 10.10.171.160 1523

Answer (score 1):

You can use jdbc Data Source configured on your WL server.

```
public static Optional<Connection> getDBConnection() {
  Optional<Connection> conn = Optional.empty();
  Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
  env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
  
  try {
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/operationsDB");
    conn = Optional.of(ds.getConnection());
    
    logger.log(
      Level.INFO, "Database connection established successfully return with connection object");
  
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
  } catch (NamingException e) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getExplanation(), e);
}
return conn;
```

}